# Ways to delete a line in vim

Tags: vim

I need to delete several lines in vim (line 42,line 424 and line 4242). I found 2 possible solutions:

- Move the cursor to the beginning of that line and then press 'dd' or
- Type ':42d' etc...

However, to get the task done, I have to delete all the 3 lines. Should I do something like this?
`:42d`
`:423d`
`:4240d`

Or this?

`:4242d`
`:424d`
`:42d`

Once I do this, I need to replace the 42nd occurrence of a word with another word (replace "Vader" with "Vader(father figure)"). I looked for "Vader" by typing 42/Vader, then entered the 'INSERT' mode and replaced the word. The problem I encounter here is that a checker is telling me that the original file does not contain the correct information. I think there is a problem with the lines deletion. Or am I failing to replace "Vader" with "Vader(father figure)" ?

Comment: Your search for the 42nd match via `42/Vader` looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you really start with the line numbers, I would delete from end to start, to avoid offset calculation. You can concatenate all `:delete` commands in a single command-line:

```
:4242d|424d|42d
```

By the way, you don't need Vim for that; a scripted solution can be done with Unix tools like `sed -i -e 4242d -e 424d -e 42d`.

But far more often, you don't start with line numbers, but instead navigate to the lines, e.g. by search. Then, the usual sequence is `dd` (delete current line), `n` (go to next match), `.` (repeat).

Answer (score 1):

The first task could be done with:

```
:4242dd|424d|42d<CR>
```

or:

```
4242Gdd424G.42G.
```

Note the reverse order, necessary for maintaining line numbering throughout the task.

---

```
gg42/Vader<CR>
```

is a safer way to search for the 42nd occurrence of `Vader` because it starts at the top of the buffer.

Once your cursor is on the right `Vader`, you can do:

```
cgnVader(father figure)<Esc>
```

to replace it.

You can use the unnamed register to avoid re-typing `Vader`:

```
cgn<C-r>"(father figure)<Esc>
```

But it's probably better to make your search land on the last character of your match:

```
/Vader/e<CR>
a(father figure)<Esc>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention something: I am asked to replace the 42nd occurrence of `Vader`, and I noticed that throughout the text, this word is merged with ", " , " ' " " . " " ! " or "?". So if i find something like `Vader's` should I count it or  not? I think I have to skip these occurrences...

Comment: That's a question for the person whom asked you to do that.

Comment: You are right. Meanwhile I asked him this and there is no difference between the 2 alternatives.